# Count the cells value by different color specified

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Please need your help on count the cells value by different color specified.

In one sheet, some cells filled with **red color**, some cells filled with **blue color**, some cells filled with **green color**. The output should be cells count red color, cells count of blue color and cells count of green color separately.

This is what I've tried:

```
Function CountByColor(InputRange As Range, ColorRange As Range) As Long

    Dim cl As Range
    TempCount As Long
    ColorIndex As Integer

    ColorIndex = ColorRange.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex TempCount = 0
    For Each cl In InputRange.Cells
        If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex
        Then
        TempCount = TempCount + 1
        End If
    Next cl
    Set cl = Nothing CountByColor = TempCount
End Function
```

Comment: I have tried with below codeFunction CountByColor(InputRange As Range, ColorRange as Range) As Long
Dim cl As Range, TempCount As Long, ColorIndex As Integer
    ColorIndex = ColorRange.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
    TempCount = 0
    For Each cl In InputRange.Cells
        If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex Then 
            TempCount = TempCount + 1
        End If
    Next cl
    Set cl = Nothing
    CountByColor = TempCount
End Function

Comment: but it was not working....please help me

Comment: Arul Can you edit your question and post the code there?

Answer (score 2):

Your function works as expected:-

```
Function CountByColor(InputRange As Range, ColorRange As Range) As Long
    Dim cl As Range, TempCount As Long, ColorIndex As Integer
    ColorIndex = ColorRange.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex
    TempCount = 0
    For Each cl In InputRange.Cells
        If cl.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex Then
            TempCount = TempCount + 1
        End If
    Next cl
    Set cl = Nothing
    CountByColor = TempCount
End Function
```

### Formula:

```
=CountByColor(A:A,A2)
```

Here `A2 Cell` is filled with `Green` and Green color index is `14`

### Result:

For my sheet, I got the result as

```
3
```

Basically you need to execute this formula for three times to get three results

```
=CountByColor(A:A,A2)   // A2 filled with Green
=CountByColor(A:A,A6)   // A6 filled with Red
=CountByColor(A:A,A9)   // A9 filled with Blue
```

Comment: @arul -> this is a solution in VBA. This is a custom built function that would be inserted into a module and used by Siva's Formula: section above. If you want to call it from inside another procedure, call it by name  and pass the two ranges for evaluation.