# Return a 0 when the date is <today

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, percentage, conditional-formatting

I have Conditioned all cells to turn red when the date is past today's date but now I would like it to return a 0 instead of the date that is currently in the cell. All the cells are vlookup from other worksheets. Ideally I would like it to work out the percentage of how many cells are highlighted at the bottom.

Comment: Should the title have been 'Return a 0 when the date is >today'?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a new column and then write a formula. Suppose the cell that has the date is A1, then the formula would be `=IF(A1=TODAY(),0,1)`

Basically, the formula will tag all dates that are today as `0` and everything else as `1`. If you want to return another value besides `1`, then you can switch out that `1` for something else (e.g. `=IF(A1=TODAY(),0,A1`)

Just fill out the rest of the column by dragging down the formula!

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Is there any way I can just count how many cells are highlighted red and then turn that into a percentage

Comment: @Sarah-Jane Yes, this goes into the realm of VBA then. You would have to write a custom excel function for doing this. Here are some links:
[here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1155-excel-count-sum-cells-by-color.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703288/count-the-cells-value-by-different-color-specified)

Comment: @Sarah-Jane No problem! Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

The following formula will give you the percentage of the cells in column A, where the datevalue is smaller then today's date. No VBA Requiered.

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"<"&TODAY())/COUNTA(A:A)
```

Do not put this formula in the same column as your data.

If you want to turn the datevalues that are smaller than today into 0, you  can use something like this:

```
=if((your VLookup-formula)<today(),0,your VLookup-formula)
```

The formula that calculates the percentage will still work. You may have to adjust your conditional formating. Make the cell red when the value is 0.

Comment: For percentage calculation shouldn't the formula be `=COUNTIF(A:A,">0")/COUNTA(A:A)*100`

Comment: I prefer to format the cell to hold a percentage, instead of multiplying by 100. Furthermore your formula would return the percentage of the dates that are not turned into 0. The result should be the percentage of the dates that are turned into 0.

Comment: Don't mind the formula it was just for example to show the multiplication by 100 for percentage.